# Encode JSON From MySQL Fetch Assoc & Fetch Array

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have this PHP syntax and works as I expected :

```
$sqldata = mysql_query("
SELECT FirstName, LastName, NumberOfChildren, SchoolTuition FROM User WHERE User.Username = '$Username' LIMIT 1;
");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

now, the problem is I want to calculate total school tuition (NumberOfChildren * SchoolTuition) and it must be done before json_encode() function. and my client doesn't want to add one extra column on their database.

so I must calculate this TOTAL School Tuition using PHP and put it back on $rows array as latest value of array before json_encode.

I tried calculate using mysql_fetch_array first to get $rows[2] and $rows[3], but since I already use mysql_fetch_assoc before, this mysql_fetch_array won't work.

last thing, I mysql_fetch_assoc generates 2 dimensional array. because when I use print_r($rows), I see this :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [FirstName] => Mary [LastName] => Smith [NumberOfChildren] => 3 [SchoolTuition] => 2000 ) )
```

while array_push function only used to push 1 dimensional array, right?

please kindly give me solution of this problem. thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do the calculation in SQL, without having to add the column.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, NumberOfChildren, SchoolTuition, 
    (NumberOfChildren * SchoolTuiton) AS TotalSchoolTuiton 
FROM User WHERE User.Username = '$Username' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You beat me by 19 seconds ... +1

Comment: And I even added an explanation! ;)

Comment: And added braces for clarity ;)

Comment: Guys, TotalSchoolTuition now have this number format : 6000.0000. there are 4 zeros as decimal number. how to remove this? FYI, NumberOfChildren and SchoolTuition are Integer on SQL structure. but why the result of calculation produce decimal number? thanks.

Comment: ... which is why I gave a +1 ;-)

Comment: @RobertHanson 
SQL will never add 4 zeros after multiplying 2 integers. Run the query in your database management system (Navicat, MySQL Workbench, PhpMyAdmin) and see what the _actual_ result is. If it's 6000 there, you do something strange to the number after fetching it. If the result is 6000.0000 in your DBMS too, then there's some kind of MySQL configuration I never ever heard of you've been tweaking with.

Comment: solved with TRUNCATE() or ROUND(). no problem with decimal now... thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, NumberOfChildren, SchoolTuition, NumberOfChildren*SchoolTuition AS TotalTuition FROM User WHERE User.Username = '$Username' LIMIT 1;
```